# ITEAD Core A20 cant load or Proceed to the FileSytem

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, embedded, deployment

i have an ITEAD CORE AW2041, which i wanted to deploy some image on it, i got the image on an sd card but when i deploy it on the device, the booting process gets stuck at the kernel level, any heads up on what i may be missing or need to tweak to get the RFS deployed? Here is the image i get after booting and it gets stuck over here. i am sure i have dd the image correctly on the sd butcant proceedd from here. [image]

and here is the image 4 the 2 partitions on the SD

[image]

The contents of the partitions r as shown below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i had not provided the correct port for the memory card. i had to edit the script.fex and generate another script.bin and the system booted successful. different boards have different ports. My board was an ITEAD AW2041. and it previous hanged at the same point awaiting on the mmcblk0p2